# Accessing books.google.com in Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, urlfetch

I'm a newbie in google appengine java. I'm having a hard time to create a web crawler in it. One solution I'm thinking and studying on is by using urlFetch() to access books.google.com. I need to input a certain isbn of a book and the app will fetch the details (title,authors,etc) of that certain book. Is it possible using urlFetch()? Thanks for the advices. :)

Answer (score 0):

Google books has an [API](http://code.google.com/apis/books/). You can access that over URLFetch just as you would any other HTTP-based API or site.